# Is it possible to use OpenCL via ssh?

Tags: ssh, opencl, remote-server

My apologies if this is a question with a simple answer, but Google didn't give me a definitive result, so I'm hoping someone here will've had some experience.

I want to start experimenting with openCL, but my current laptop isn't compatible.

Is there any reason I couldn't use a service like https://www.digitalocean.com/ (or one of the many like it) and run my OpenCL code on it via SSH?

Has anyone had any experience doing something like that? And if so, is it manageable? Or does it end up being more trouble than it's worth. It seems like it could work, but I'm very new to OpenCL, so I could be completely wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your laptop has SSE4.2 you can run the Intel OpenCL CPU driver.
And even if it has something older than that you can likely run the AMD OpenCL CPU driver.
These will let you get your feet wet with the API and write some host and device (OpenCL C) code.

I don't know anything about the service you linked to but I know that Amazon has some instances that include GPU resources that are OpenCL capable (NVIDIA K20 and others).

Comment: Yeah, using OpenCL on an Amazon EC2 instance is definitely possible. You just have to make sure you set up the include paths correctly and link against the proper `libOpenCL.so` library. See these instructions: http://kylelutz.blogspot.com/2014/04/using-opencl-with-boostcompute-on.html